# How to install jdk, jdeveloper, maven and svn in one docker container?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I want to create development environment for all our programmers so I want to install jdk, jdeveloper, maven and svn in one docker container.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to go to the docker site and learn how to create a `Dockerfile`. The file will run and create a container with whatever you want to install in it. For example:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yqq\
openjdk-8-jre\
maven\
svn\
....

RUN ... (to run commands inside the container when it's created)
EXPOSE 80 8080... (whatever ports  you want to expose)
```

This is a very simple example, you have to read the docs and see what is available. I would recommend looking at the Dockerfile for from the github repo that has all the library docker files and get an idea of what's happening so you know how to create your container.

On a side note, I would not install svn in the same container, it would be better to have it in a separate container so that you never have more than one service per container since each container runs in a separate process. You can link containers, but that would require reading the docs to see how that is done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why using jdeveloper? For eclipse you can find several examples in the docker hub.

Agree with @Hatem-Jaber seperate svn from the dev environment.